# python: calculate steps for dreamcatcher

Tags: python

i am currently stuck trying to calculate a dreamcatcher and its inner circles. basically you have a outer circle with given radius `x` and you need to calculate its perimeter. then you would have to calculate a magic value that is how wide every bow (in the image the stuff with the numbers) should be and it should result that the bows will not finish at the start point but overlapp about half a bow with the first.

[image: how it is done]

here is what i tried so far:

```
import math

# in cm
rad = 5.0

perimeter = round(rad * 2.0 * math.pi, 2)
print "perimeter == %f" % perimeter

#bow = "?"
incValue = 0.00001
start = incValue
end = perimeter
while start < end / 10:
  tmp = start * 10
  while tmp < perimeter:
    tmp += start

  if tmp - perimeter == start / 2:
    print "bow could be %s" % str(tmp)

  start += incValue

print "done"
```

but i am not able to find a value that fits that constraints.

Comment: I think `if tmp - perimeter == start / 2` is problematic because floating point numbers rarely compare equal to one another so neatly. You might need to implement some kind of `very_nearly_equals(a,b)` that returns True when `abs(a-b) < some_very_small_number`. In any case, Can't you find the value you want with `bow_length = perimeter / (desired_number_of_full_bows + 0.5)`?

Comment: Can you demonstrate that what you mean exactlly by wide of every bow?

Comment: @Kasra is it enought to say `wide of every bow` is equal to distance between (for example in the picture) `Erste Umschlingung` and `2`?

Comment: @Kevin Or you could `if abs(tmp - perimeter - (start / 2)) > threshold` with `threshold` being the maximum deflection you want to accept.

Comment: @Kasra think of `bow` is the distance on the circle where the knots will be

Comment: @Kevin i like the simple aproach. if you give me an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get the value you want with

```
bow_length = perimeter / (desired_number_of_full_bows + 0.5)
```

---

But if you're really interested in getting your approximation system working, I think this line is causing problems:

```
if tmp - perimeter == start / 2:
```

floating point numbers rarely compare equal to one another, so it is conventional to instead check that they are very close together. So you might instead do:

```
if abs((tmp - perimeter) - (start / 2)) < epsilon:
```

... Where `epsilon` represents the largest possible "wiggle room" between two numbers that you would be willing to accept. It would be something like 0.0001, although you could experiment with larger or smaller values to see what works best.